# Secure copy between two remote hosts

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to copy from two remote hosts, from another host.
i.e. Say A is my local host. and B, C are my remote hosts.
How do I copy from B to C being hosted at A?
something like this:

```
user@A:~#  scp user@B:~/text user@C:~/.
```

Thanks.

Edit: There is another thread for the same problem here - [How to transfer a file between two remote servers using scp from a third, local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831329/how-to-transfer-a-file-between-two-remote-servers-using-scp-from-a-third-local)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`ssh user@B 'scp ./file user@C:'`

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the only way out. In my problem, I iterate through different hosts, and copy files from one to the other. But at some point, it comes down to the local host itself being one of them. in such cases, say when C is the local host itself, but I have no way of knowing that (yet),
when I ssh into B and try to ssh back to the local host from B, I'm not granted permission.
That's the problem I'm trying to tackle.